# Comment edit area very small

Tags: feature-request, support

Why is the comment area for typing text so small ? Often I find myself squinting as I type a comment. Can it be increased in size, to at least the size of the max amount of comment characters ? Note, I just find this problematic when trying to scroll comment box, especially when attempting to check the readability of a comment prior to posting. Might be nice if there was a preview feature as a comment was typed....

Comment: Sounds like your comment are too long ;)

Comment: In my browser (FF) I can re-size the comment box downwards, but not sideways.

Comment: @vasco got lost I did'nt notice that option, thanks

Comment: @vasco got lost if you put your last option into an answer I'll accept it, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too small you say?  I agree!  That's why, when I'm planning on writing a larger comment, I'll use some of the popular browsers' (Chrome/Firefox AFAIK) textarea resizing  functionality.   Just grab onto it and pull!

> ```
>              Chrome                                    Firefox
> ```
>
> [image]                             
>   [image]

It's not a solution, it's not denying your feature request - it's just a workaround :)

[image]

Comment: +1 for freehand circles